# Please reopen my question about hashes?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

The text of the close message above my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59233177/which-hash-algorhythms-do-google-facebook-etc-use-to-hash-millions-of-filen) said: " Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations.  "

So my question might have been unclear on that, and I made some text passeges bold, because I actually wanted facts and citations.

Are those close messages very generic, by the way?

[Which hash algorhythms do google, facebook, etc... use to hash millions of filenames in the same category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59233177/which-hash-algorhythms-do-google-facebook-etc-use-to-hash-millions-of-filen)

Comment: Yes they are generic. There are thousands of questions each day, not all do fit here.

Comment: Who is supposed to answer your question? Someone from google? Someone from facebook? Also there are [thousands of different hashing algorithms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions)

Comment: @JonasWilms Some "expert" in this field, some former google or facebook employees, students in this field of expertise who happened to help on SO, the competition of facebook and google, someone who already searched for the answer, and searching on the internet many searched for the answer and didn't find it or didn't post their find. - So, the usual SO participants? Or maybe it's answered on SO already, so someone could post a link? - And yeah, there are thousands of different hashing algorhythms, so the chance of finding the current state of the art for myself, not being an expert, is ... 0

Comment: You will want to beware of the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) where asking a question on meta about a StackOverflow question brings additional attention to the question, and this can possibly be positive attention (up-votes and answers) or negative attention (down-votes). It can magnify the voting response to your question, and again, that's not always a good thing (for you).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you for the kind answer. I was aware of it. I just always anew wonder why people  don't read the question really. Of course, the topic of my SO question important for my project, I hoped that I got it reopened. And I only yesterday I read a blog from 2018 of a C?? of SO about what's wrong, so SO knows, but obviously  they can't tackle their problem. - Just the example below again, someone stating it would be important if I want to access or write to files, when I already stated in the second sentence of the question: "read operations". Oh well.

Comment: @John: SO is like any other tool in that it is useful for many things but not all things. I think that the problem here is that you're frustrated over asking a question that has been found off-topic. It happens, and so you move on to a different site for this question of yours, and save more SO-site appropriate questions for this one. Win-win for you and for the site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's jolly good. :) I just deliberated if I would write the same. Just, I doubt a bit if it's a win-win. More a lose-lose. - And seeing that the topic affects everyone with large amount of files, and no up-to-date answer or not even any real answer on SO, it's a magnified lose for SO.

Comment: Nah, delete the question here, ask it on Reddit or other such site, and you're better off as is the site.

Comment: @Ty. I likelly will. Or I may ask on some maillist of a big international project, where at least once a few years ago I got a spot on answer, on a spot on question. - Yeah, I think I'll try that. - They didn't know me. I didn't know them. Of course, the guy that helped got payed by the project. Maybe that's a reason.

Comment: And I was a little bit teased to write on meta, I have to admit, by the close message: "Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations." It came accoss as a little bit irrational to me when I explicitly asked for actual in use hash algorhytms (facts), literature (citations) and developers' blogs (facts and citations). :)

Comment: That looks to be asking for a graduate project research thesis requesting a lot of in-depth research for a volunteer site.

Comment: I'm sure the question would have been answered after a few days, when people who work on the area (filesystem access) visit SO themselves and follow one of the SO suggested links. Good luck!

Comment: @John I'm pretty sure when HFOE referenced 'another site', they didn't mean on SE, much less for you to violate the rules on another SE site.  Resource requests are off topic both here and on SF.

Comment: I work at Microsoft and I don't use hashes of file names or files. Does this satisfy your curiosity? or you actually want to ask every single person of Microsoft, Google, Amazon, Netflix, Dropbox,...? Pure curiosity based questions are rarely fare well on SO (especially if one get popular or posted on meta)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I can't see that I added that I meant they use it for uploaded files of the users, my mistake. At least that's what I read on SO on old answers to old questions. And bet my pardon, many links at facebook and google look like they use hashes, for example: (I had a not feasible example.). But that's only google, I see. And wikipedia. And Facebook according to a post on SO. (I better not trust google patents, facebook infos or wikipedia/wikimedia people anymore. Not to mention old SO answers!)

Answer (score 10):

I see no reason to.

Your *issue* (e.g. files that have similar names) is only loosely related to the *question* you're asking (e.g. what hashing algorithms are in use at major tech companies).

The loose and faint correlation is that, somehow, some way, hashing the files will make it easier to manage them.

[We call these "XY Problems"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/175248); you're asking about a potential solution to your problem instead of your actual problem, which serves to confuse experts or anyone capable of answering your question.

What you're lacking from the question you *actually* wanted to ask, which was:

> I have a lot (on the order of a million) of files with similar file names.  I have [INSERT OPERATION/PROGRAM/ROUTINE HERE] that has to go through these files with similar names with [INSERT CONCRETE CONDITION/HEURISTIC HERE], but I've noticed that it's slow.  How could I demonstrably speed it up in terms of [INSERT SPEED-UP CRITERIA HERE]?  I've tried [INSERT CONCRETE ATTEMPT HERE] with [REFERENCE OPERATION/PROGRAM/ROUTINE], but it doesn't seem to have made much of a difference.

... are key details:

- *Where* are these files stored? (AWS, GCP, Azure, personal disk, personal cloud, etc)
- *Why* do they have similar file names and why is that significant?
- *What* are you doing with the files and what is the operation you're running on them?
- *What* do you define as an "improvement"?  Is it raw processing speed or something else?

Until such a time that your question is actually better framed as the problem you're actually intending to solve, there's really no reason to reopen it.

Comment: I only read yesterday about the "XY Problems", and the misconceptions of those who fall for believing they have spotted such a case in a question were already pointed  out many times in the comments and answers to such threads. - But as example I'll answer your four W-questions: Where? It doesn't matter,  it's  a mathematical problem that EVERYONE has who is running a filesystem, in this case my OS on my laptop. (It's blazing fast btw with a NvmeSSD.I dare say 99% of SO users here have a more expensive but slower system.) - Why: Nature. What: I asked for the accessing. .05*1e6=5e4, every day

Comment: To counter, @John:  It *does* matter, since there's a difference between storing and accessing millions of files in S3 as opposed to a local disk (be it spinny or solid-state).  This is a *solved* mathematical problem in the sense that most systems have services which do some kind of indexing operation on the file(s) it's aware of, but this is ***wholly*** dependent on the system you're running on, and how you're actually accessing the files.  That again leads to the point of why the similar name issue actually matters.

Comment: The more details you supply to potential answers in a question like this, the *better* chances you're going to have of it being well received.  Remember:  you're asking for *our* time.  What we ask for in return is that you meet us at least half-way.

Comment: Or to be more precise instead of ".05*1e6=5e4, every day", let's say: (visit each day) * count(fileaccess) * + (at least) .05*1e6*2. At least.

Comment: Ok. you haven't read my question: "read operations", it's in the question.

Comment: "Read operations" is fairly broad and ill-defined.  Files are read all the time, but that doesn't quite answer why you believe that hashing the file would improve that.  It also doesn't answer the question why the file names being slightly similar is a problem, either.  Details like this make for either an answerable question or a closed question, in all honesty.

Comment: @John I don't understand what is so difficult about giving some specifics of the system you have in mind. It's not much work and will result in helpful answers. Isn't that what you want? Trust us, we need a bit more context and are really good if you give it to us.

Answer (score 2):

> Are those close messages very generic, by the way?

Yup. You can [read up on them here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide), [and here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow). They are quite generic.

---

> So my question might have been unclear on that, and I made some text passeges bold, because I actually wanted facts and citations.

While it is good to make sure your question **can** be answered with facts and citations, it's off-topic to ask for those citations--explicitly or implied. For instance, your language here is problematic (emphasis mine):

> Which hash algorhythms are in use at google, facebook, apple, microsoft, ...? (Facts.) **There must surely be literature** (citations?) **or developers' blogs** (facts and citations) out there that detail which algorhythms have turned out to be most efficient for this task.

I absolutely agree: surely there must be something like this somewhere. But asking us to find them is asking us to find them for you (which is sort of implied) is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as now you at the very least dangerously close (at best) to asking for off-site resources:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

---

> Reopen my question about hashes?

I would vote no. Your question appears to be asking for off-site resources, which is of-topic, even with your edits.

Even if it wasn't doing that, your question also needs more focus, as Google, Facebook, Apple, and Microsoft are all large companies that outsiders probably have no way of telling what they use. In fact, some of these algorithms might be proprietary and may not be able to be shared anyway.

There's also another problem: explaining these algorithms sufficiently would be very hard to do in this format. We really couldn't do them justice, even *if* we knew what they were.

So over all, your question should probably remain closed. Sorry. I'm afraid that, as your question is currently written, that's just the way it is.